# Chef client configuration without storing private key

Tags: chef-infra, hashicorp-vault

Is there any method to register Chef client with a Chef server without physically storing the private key on the Chef client ?

Can the `Hashicorp vault` fit in here and solve the problem of storing the key file on disk ?

If yes, what steps have to be followed for the configurations ?

Comment: Turns out this is not possible unless we write our own Vault / Chef plugin. Did verify in the Chef community mailing list.

Comment: I don't really understand why one would need this. If an attacker gains root, they will be able to read all files, all process memory, Vault, dm-crypt…

Answer (score 0):

[depending on the chef version that you are using](https://blog.chef.io/validatorless-bootstraps/), the [chef-validator key](https://docs.chef.io/auth.html#chef-validator) in order to register a node on the chef-server.

in the process of node registration, a private key for the node is generated and used for authenticating the node each time the node tried to access the chef server (to synchronize the cookbook and to post node state).

this implies that you can delete the validator key at the end of the node bootstrapping, and this is the *best practice*. you can do that by leveraging [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client#delete_validation)

if an attacker gets the chef-validator key, the attacker can trick the chef server and pull all of the cookbooks.

Comment: An attacker can pull all cookbooks and data bags with the regular client-key as well. The validator-key was only used to register the client (create a client public/private key). However if an attacker manages to infiltrate the machine, one can easily dump the memory while chef - or any other program that uses secrets - runs.

Comment: @Roland: this is out of scope, i just wanted to bring into attention the security concerns about it. more of which, using the client-key, an attacker can only pull the current node cookbooks.